# GRUB Repair with Windows 10 Dual Boot Arch Linux

Tags: linux, multi-boot, grub

I've been using Arch Linux for 4 months and I was trying to have Dual Boot with Windows 10. After the installation of Windows 10 and formatting the disk again it went great, zero problems, but, when I try to boot Arch Linux with my USB GRUB menu shows.

Before GRUB menu shows, it says "Unknown TPM Error" and typing in the command line of the GRUB menu `set` it shows this information:

```
?='0'
cmdpath='(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/BOOT'
color_highlight='black/light-gray'
color_normal='light-gray/black'
feature_200_final='y'
feature_all_video_module='y'
feature_chainloader_bpb='y'
feature_default_font_path='y'
feature_menuentry_id='y'
feature_menuentry_options='y'
feature_nativedisk_cmd='y'
feature_ntldr='y'
feature_platform_search_hint='y'
feature_timeout_style='y'
grub_cpu='x86_64'
grub_platform='efi'
lang=''
locale_dir=''
net_default_ip=''
net_default_mac=''
net_default_server=''
pager=''
prefix='(memdisk)/boot/grub'
pxe_default_server=''
root='memdisk'
secondary_locale_dir=''
error: unknown TPM error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some weeks of researching and chatting with people I've reached an temporal solution for this problem.

This error is caused (obviously) for the TPM, to proceed with the Arch Linux or other Linux distro installation when the GRUB prompt appears it will be necessary to write into the prompt `rmmod tpm`, after this command is executed it will output `error: unknown TPM error`, but, typing again the command will say `error: no such module` saying that TPM is now removed.

After deleting TPM the next thing is writing `normal` in the GRUB prompt, it will vanish and continue to the GRUB menu, where Arch Linux can be installed as usual.

I hope someone looking for help with this error find this question.